# fullCalendar calendar div doesn't show on device with phonegap

Tags: html, cordova, fullcalendar

fullCalendar doesn't show the calendar on PhoneGap when launched on device (Android ICS).

However the content is loaded via Chrome or Firefox, it loads normally and the content can be seen. I've also tried to run the fullCalendar demos by itself without any custom code inside phonegap and the calendar does not render.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>a</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery.mobile-1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print">
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.mobile-1.1.1/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.mobile-1.1.1/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.mobile-1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,today,next',
                right: 'agendaDay'

            },
            defaultView: "agendaDay",
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                if (title) {
                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                        {
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            allDay: allDay
                        },
                        true // make the event "stick"
                    );
                }
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
            editable: true,
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'Morning Status Meeting',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 9, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch meeting with John Appleseed',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d, 13, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Android Product Review',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d, 15, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Andrew and Matthew\'s baseball finals',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 17, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d, 19, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
            ]
        });

    });

</script>

    <style type='text/css'>
        body {
            margin-top: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
            }

        #wrap {
            width: 400px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            }

        #external-events {
            float: left;
            width: 150px;
            padding: 0 10px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            background: #eee;
            text-align: left;
            }

        #external-events h4 {
            font-size: 16px;
            margin-top: 0;
            padding-top: 1em;
            }

        .external-event { /* try to mimick the look of a real event */
            margin: 10px 0;
            padding: 2px 4px;
            background: #3366CC;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: .85em;
            cursor: pointer;
            }

        #external-events p {
            margin: 1.5em 0;
            font-size: 11px;
            color: #666;
            }

        #external-events p input {
            margin: 0;
            vertical-align: middle;
            }

        #calendar {
            float: right;
            width: 400px;
            background-color: white;
            }

    </style>

 </head>
<body> 
    <!-- Start of first page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="service-booking" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Service Appointment Booking</h1>
            <a href="index.html" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right">Options</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">

        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a" width="300">
            <div id='wrap'>
                <div id='calendar'></div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /grid-a -->
        </div><!-- /content -->
    </div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Found the solution to my own problem. Needed to remove <!-- and --> from HTML, and also any // comments from Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I have some problems showing margin on Android. Try without margin.